# Generate migrations & models from existing database in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, laravel, migration

We have a realtime application running on Laravel with a postgreSQL database and an AngularJS frontend. Since NodeJS offers better functionality for realtime applications we want to migrate our Laravel backend to a NodeJS environtment with Express and Sequelizejs.

We walking now into an issue that we need to build all the migrations and models again. But I'm wondering if there is any way to generate migrations & models in sequelizejs (or another library) from an existing postgreSQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto

This module can do the job for you.

Comment: nice thank you! Any module which could do the same with generating migrations?

Comment: maybe this can help http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/

Comment: he Asif, yes I looked into that but it doesn't seem to be capable of generating migrations backwards from the db. But thats okay!